# Django REST serializer, how to add extra field and set it

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I need your help, extending classes is beyond my current Python skills.

Django 3.1 and Django-Rest-Framework.

I would like to add "detail_url" field to VideoSerializer, and set its value based on existing field on model. "detail_url" is not defined in model, I would like to generate it on the fly when view is called. I figure, serializer is the best place to do it.

Thank you

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.urls import reverse
from main.models import Video


class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    detail_url = serializers.URLField()

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['uuid', 'url', 'title', 'thumbnail_url', 'detail_url']
        # fields = '__all__'
    
    detail_url = reverse('video_detail', args=[model.uuid]) # <- this is the part I dont know where to declare
```

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user
       
        # retrieve user's videos
        videos = Video.objects.filter(user=user)
        if videos.exists():
            serializer = VideoSerializer(videos, many=True)
            context['videos'] = json.dumps(serializer.data)

        return render(request, 'main/dashboard.html', context)
```

Comment: serializers.SerializerMethodField()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`serializermethodfield`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) when you want to add a field that is the result of a method

```
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    detail_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_detail_url(self, obj):
        return reverse('video_detail', obj.uuid)
```